# Jquery: Pick out items that don't have class A or B

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to pick elements that don't have wither one of two classes `A` or `B`.  I can write the case where the elements don't have one class

```
$(element).find("thead > tr.column-headers td:not(.A)");

$(element).find("thead > tr.column-headers td:not(.B)");
```

But I want a single selector for not A and not B.  This does not work

```
$(element).find("thead > tr.column-headers td:not(.A) td:not(.B)");
```

Comment: A selector containing `td:not(.A) td:not(.B)` attempts to find the `td` element whose class is not A, then looks within that element to find a second `td` *child* whose class is not B.

Comment: It should be noted that the `:not` selector accepts a comma seperated list as well, so all you need to do is just add `.B` to the first one `td:not(.A, .B)` -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/L1x5x008/

Comment: Note that the comma separated list support is limited to jQuery not selectors. It isn't valid in a CSS not selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`td:not(.A) td:not(.B)` means "A td that is not a member of class B and is also a descendant of another td that is not a member of class A".

You need to put both the not rules on the **same element**.

```
thead > tr.column-headers td:not(.A):not(.B)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(element).find("thead > tr.column-headers").not("td.A, td.B");
```